# How to fetch the dropdown values from database and display in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have two dropdowns in jsp and have to get dropdown list from database and show it in jsp. I am using jsp for the first time . Can you give me an idea to fetch the dropdown list from database and display the values in jsp dropdown element.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***how to fetch the dropdown values from database and display in jsp:***

*Dynamically Fetch data from Mysql to (drop down) select option in Jsp. This post illustrates, to fetch the data from the mysql database and display in select option element in Jsp. You should know the following post before going through this post i.e :*

***How to Connect Mysql database to jsp.***

*How to create database in MySql and insert data into database.
Following database is used, to illustrate ‘Dynamically Fetch data from Mysql to (drop down)*

***select option in Jsp’ :***

```
id  City
1   London
2   Bangalore
3   Mumbai
4   Paris
```

*Following codes are used to insert the data in the MySql database. Database used is “City” and username = “root” and password is also set as “root”.*

```
Create Database city;
Use city;
```

---

```
Create table new(id int(4), city varchar(30));
```

---

```
insert into new values(1, 'LONDON');
insert into new values(2, 'MUMBAI');
insert into new values(3, 'PARIS');
insert into new values(4, 'BANGLORE');
```

***Here is the code to Dynamically Fetch data from Mysql to (drop down) select option in Jsp:***

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%ResultSet resultset =null;%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Select element drop down box</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR=##f89ggh>

<%
    try{
//Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = 
         DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/city?user=root&password=root");

       Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;

       resultset =statement.executeQuery("select * from new") ;
%>

<center>
    <h1> Drop down box or select element</h1>
        <select>
        <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
            <option><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
        <% } %>
        </select>
</center>

<%
//**Should I input the codes here?**
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             out.println("wrong entry"+e);
        }
%>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

[image]

Comment: ok but i have a jsp like this  that is a country dropdown and state dropdown

Comment: @user2585622, hey its just sample code... you should must want to alternate the code your self...that was simple you just copy and paste  this code and add the country...

Comment: ok but i have a jsp like this  that is a country dropdown and state dropdown and also have made a connection to db in dao and got the dropdown values in DAO.my question is how to call that DAO from jsp and display the dropdown list

Comment: you are mention only jsp that only I'll post the jsp page...if you want like dao and servelt you should must add the servlet tag and you should mention the servlet dao

Comment: ok sure using it for the first time how to get the dropdown list . have the list in dao . how to retrieve in jsp

Comment: how to set option value as well from database, ie. <option value=????>London</option>

Answer (score 6):

You can learn some tutorials for JSP page direct access database (mysql) [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)

Notes:

- import sql tag library in jsp page

  `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>`
- then set datasource on page

  ```
  <sql:setDataSource var="ds" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://<yourhost>/<yourdb>" user="<user>" password="<password>"/>
  ```
- Now query what you want on page

  ```
  <sql:query dataSource="${ds}" var="result"> //ref  defined 'ds'
      SELECT * from <your-table>;
  </sql:query>
  ```
- Finally you can populate dropdowns on page using `c:forEach` tag to iterate result rows in `select` element

  `<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">   //ref set var 'result'
        <option value='<c:out value="${row.key}"/>'><c:out value="${row.value}"/</option>
  </c:forEach>`

Comment: thanks but i have got the dropdown list in DAO from db. can you please let me know how to call the dao from jsp and display the dropdown list

Comment: You should ask question with details that you want next time. Your question means you want access JSP page to database. Can you edit your question with more details? Whether you use Spring or EJB, JPA, and so on?

Comment: sure i have a jsp and i have made an ajax call from javascript  to  DAO where i have retrieve the details for the dropdown list. Now how do i display it in jsp means how to call the javascript function for displaying the dropdown list

Comment: Pls edit your question with more details of DAO and javascript ajax usage. So that help will come soon. Can you debug ajax respnse with 'console.log'?

Comment: i have retrieved the details from database by making an ajax call. My question is how to display it in jsp dropdown. I have used javascript and made an ajax to get the values from database.

Comment: generic comment for generic question..
code javascript to iterate and populate dropdown list value from ajax response, then render like `document.getElementById('<your-selectlist-id>').innerHTML = <populated-dropdowns>;`

Answer (score 5):

I made this in my code to do that

note:
I am a beginner.

It is my jsp code.

```
<%
java.sql.Connection Conn = DBconnector.SetDBConnection(); /* make connector as you make in your code */
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
st = Conn.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from department"); %>
<tr> 
    <td> 
        Student Major  : <select name ="Major">
        <%while(rs.next()){ %>
        <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>
                        <%}%>           
                         </select> 
   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the database connection and retrieve the query result.
2. Traverse through the result and display the query results.

The example code below demonstrates this in detail.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*, java.io.*,listresult"%> //import the required library

<%

String label = request.getParameter("label"); // retrieving a variable from a previous page

Connection dbc = null; //Make connection to the database
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
dbc = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/works", "root", "root");
if (dbc != null) 
{
    System.out.println("Connection successful");
}

ResultSet rs = listresult.dbresult.func(dbc, label); //This function is in the end. The function is defined in another package- listresult

%>

<form name="demo form" method="post">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Label Name:
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="label" value="<%=rs.getString("labelname")%>">
            </td>

            <td>
                <select name="label">
                <option value="">SELECT</option>

                <% while (rs.next()) {%>

                    <option value="<%=rs.getString("lname")%>"><%=rs.getString("lname")%>
                    </option>

                <%}%>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

//The function:

public static ResultSet func(Connection dbc, String x)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    try
    {
        sql = "select lname from demo where label like '" + x + "'";
        pst = dbc.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String sqlMessage = e.getMessage();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

I have tried to make this example as detailed as possible. Do ask if you have any queries.