# How can I show column data from my databasel in a drop down menu as selections?

Tags: php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, mysqli

When my page loads it has a form with a hidden input that is named “email”.  This input value is equal to that of a logged in users email and loads this value automatically upon page load.

How can I show column data based on email in a drop down menu as selections?

This is what I'm trying to do:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/258tmhd.jpg

**Heres my Code thats not working:**

```
<html>
<header>



</header>

<body>




<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");

// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}


$query = "SELECT itemname FROM seguin_orders";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>




<select name="xxx"><option value="">-- Select One --</option>


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo("<option value=". $row['itemname'] . ">". $row['itemname'] ."</option>");
  }

</select>






<form action="/demoform/contact_form.php" class="well" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" novalidate="">



<input type="text" required id="mile" name="mile" placeholder="Miles"/>

</br>

<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text" value="demo@gmail.com" readonly="readonly"/>

</br>

<input id="name" name="itemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME 1" required="" type="text" />

</br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset" />


<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>









</body>


</html>
```

Comment: So you want the user to enter an email and then load the data according to the entered email?

If so, you probably want to learn [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and specifically [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: actually no...a user does not enter in there email

Comment: the input value already has an email value

Comment: Do you want to group the items in the select box like this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

Comment: @SteveBrown Robin has pretty much answered your question. You can achieve your goal by using JQuery and ajax calls.

Comment: I think he means a while loop that creates an option for every value in the database right?

Comment: @robin thanks for your help...yea trying to get values from my database from under the itemname column into the dropdown menu select box...

Comment: the email value is the value that is used to determine which item name values to show in the drop down menu

Comment: @SteveBrown look at Luna NA's link at the bottom of his answer, there is a full tutorial there

Answer (score 0):

You could write a servlet where you get the email with `request.getParameter(email)`

The SQL statement should be something like this (use preparedstatement):

```
SELECT itemname FROM table_A WHERE email=?
```

then set your String with `ps.setString(1, email);`, execute the Query, pass the results to an arraylist and then forward them back to your jsp where you want to show your results.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550913/how-to-fetch-the-dropdown-values-from-database-and-display-in-jsp) also