# How to select a value in drop down according to value from database in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I have a drop down field in html and i am getting some value from database. Now what i wanted to do is automatically select the same value in drop down that i have got from the database. Here is the code of my drop down. As i have approx 30 values in drop down so if conditions in jsp might not be helpful

```
<select class="textbox" id="State" name="State" style="margin-top:10px;" onblur="checkState()"required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
    <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
    <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
    <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
    <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
    <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
    <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
    <option value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
    <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
    <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
    <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
    <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
    <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
    <option value="Jammu and Kashmir">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
    <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
    <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
    <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
    <option value="Lakshadweep">Lakshadweep</option>
    <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
    <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
    <option value="Manipur">Manipur</option>
    <option value="Meghalaya">Meghalaya</option>
    <option value="Mizoram">Mizoram</option>
    <option value="Nagaland">Nagaland</option>
    <option value="Odisha">Odisha</option>
    <option value="Puducherry">Puducherry</option>
    <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
    <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
    <option value="Sikkim">Sikkim</option>
    <option value="Tamil Nadu">Tamil Nadu</option>
    <option value="Telangana">Telangana</option>
    <option value="Tripura">Tripura</option>
    <option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
    <option value="Uttarakhand">Uttarakhand</option>
    <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a AJAX call to get the selected value from database.
2. Use JQuery to make the value as selected

Try the code,

```
$.get( "/state", function( data ) {
      $("#State").val("data");
})
```

Comment: can i do it without jquery or ajax. I just want to use JSP

Comment: Did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550913/how-to-fetch-the-dropdown-values-from-database-and-display-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

In JSP code,

- Make a java list and store all state names
- Now create `select` tag
- Iterate over each state name in list
- Create `option` for each entry in list
- If a particular entry is equal to value retrieved from database, mark it as selected.